# How to automatically hide nav bar once a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I want my mobile displayed nav bar to close after one of the links is clicked. I have tried a few different options but can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions? If theres anything else thats needed to better understand the situation just let me know and I will add it. I will add my code below.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

burger.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    // TOGGLE NAV
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

//ANIMATE LINKS 
navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
    if(link.style.animation){
        link.style.animation = '';
    }   else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + .5}s`;
    }
});

//burger animation
burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

});

  }
  navSlide();
```

```html
<header class="l-header">
    <nav class="nav bd-grid">
        <a class="nav__logo" href="#">
            <div class="logo-image">
                  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="nav__logo-icon">
            </div>
            
        </a>

        
      <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a  href="./theteam.html">The Team</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Hire</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
                .bd-grid{
                max-width: 1024px;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 100%;
                grid-column-gap: 2rem;
                width: calc(100% - 2rem);
                margin-left: var(--mb-2);
                margin-right: var(--mb-2);
            }
            .l-header{
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: var(--z-fixed);
                background-color: var(--first-color);
            }





            .nav-links {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
                width: 60%;
            }

            .nav-links a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fafaff;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
            }
            .nav-links li{
                list-style: none;
            }
            .burger div{
                width:25px;
                height: 2px;
                background-color: rgb(228, 226, 226);
                margin: 5px;
                transition: all 0.3s ease;
            }
            .burger {
                display: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
                .nav-links {
                    width: 60%;
                }
                
            }



            @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
                body{
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                }
                
                .nav-links a{
                    color: var(--first-color);
                    font-size: 17px;
                }

                .nav-links {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0px;
                    height: 91vh;
                    top: 7.5vh;
                    background-color: #f3f1f1;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    width: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(100%);
                    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
                    
                }
                .nav-links li{
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                .burger{
                    display: inline-block;
                }
            }

            .nav-active{
                transform: translateX(0%);
            }

            @keyframes navLinkFade{
                from{
                    opacity: 0;
                    transform: translateX(50px);
                }
                to {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: translateX(0px);

                }
            }
            .toggle .line1 {
                transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
            }
            .toggle .line2 {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .toggle .line3 {
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
            }



            @media screen and (max-width: 428px){
                .nav-links {
                    
                    height: 93vh;
                    top: 6.9vh;
                
                }
            }

            .invisible {
                display: none;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 415px){
                .nav-links {
                    
                    height: 93vh;
                    top: 7.1vh;
                
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 390px){
                .nav-links {
                    
                    height: 93vh;
                    top: 7.9vh;
                
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 375px){
                .nav-links {
                    
                    height: 93vh;
                    top: 7.8vh;
                
                }
            }
```

Comment: As you're toggling classes you probably need to share your relevant CSS along with the above HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have added my CSS code above. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for adding the CSS, but if I add that in to the rest of the code this is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lshao29g/, which doesn't seem to accurately reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas the fiddle code result correctly represents my current code. What I'm looking to do is to have the nav bar automatically toggle back to its closed state once on of the links in the nav bar has been clicked. Almost all of the nav bar links are internal links that bring you to a section of the page I'm working on. Hopefully that helps clarify what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide it by adding a class that hides it

```js
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinkContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = navLinkContainer.querySelectorAll('li a');

//ANIMATE LINKS 
navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
        }   else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + .5}s`;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            navLinkContainer.classList.add("invisible");
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});

burger.addEventListener("click", function() {
    navLinkContainer.classList[navLinkContainer.classList.contains("invisible") ? "remove" : "add"]("invisible");
})


  }
  navSlide();
```

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="l-header">
    <nav class="nav bd-grid">
        <a class="nav__logo" href="#">
            <div class="logo-image">
                  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="nav__logo-icon">
            </div>
            
        </a>

        
      <ul class="nav-links invisible">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a  href="./theteam.html">The Team</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Hire</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
          HAM BURGER
      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I would like to kindly ask for the reason of the down-vote. If the answer is incorrect, then I'm happy to remove it. If it needs improvement, then I'm happy to edit it. Thanks!

Comment: This will not allow for an animation as he seems to attempt. Also, it should not be used in 2022 anymore. Using `classList` is the way to go for multiple reasons incl. specificity weight issues.

Comment: @tacoshy let me edit my answer.

Comment: why not just apply it to the entire nav instead of each single anchor? He even already has a line: `nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');` he just didn't shared his CSS yet to replicate the issue he has.

Comment: @tacoshy I have added the CSS code. I have also tried to implement Lajos Arpad's code but it just hid the nav bar fully. So there was no way to toggle it open or closed from the beginning.

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant "but it just hid the nav bar fully". What should be hidden? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: @tacoshy it was applied for the entire nav. The code was not well written and it had no event listener for the links, only a foreach. I added the event handlers. It's all about hiding the whole navigation, I do not know why you think that the hiding only affected an element.

Comment: @LajosArpad The nav bar should close once a link has been clicked. Once I implemented your code, I was unable to open the nav bar, it was in its 'invisible' and did not display.

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant I understand that some behavior is missing from my fiddle. Please let me know when should the nav bar be reopened, as my understanding is that it's closing correctly, but it's not reopening when it should. It's also possible that I misunderstood your previous comment, in which case I would like to kindly ask you to provide further clarifications.

Comment: @LajosArpad Currently there is a hamburger menu that when clicked opens my nav bar menu which has individual links within it. When I click the hamburger menu the nav bar should open / close. Once I click one of the links within the nav bar, the nav bar should go back to its closed state. The issue that I received when implementing your code is that I was unable to open or close the nav bar. As I clicked the hamburger menu it triggered the open / close animation showing that the hamburger menu was activating but the nav bar was not displaying. It was hidden.

Comment: @LajosArpad I have created a jsfiddle so that you can see the code better. I also added internal sections in the page so that the links in the nav bar function.      https://jsfiddle.net/w5mxevjz/

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant thanks for the details you have provided. I have edited my answer, added some inner text into your burger to make sure it's clickable and added a click event as well. Please let me know if the current version qualifies as a solution, or whether it's closer to a solution than the earlier approach.

Comment: @LajosArpad With the new code that you added, once the text "HAM BURGER" is clicked nothing happens. I will add a jsfiddle showing the result with the newly edited code added. Thank you for the help by the way, I really do appreciate the effort. https://jsfiddle.net/6gqd87rn/

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant in my snippet, by clicking on HAM BURGER the links's visibility is successfully toggled. I'm looking into your fiddle, the first thing I observe is that HAM BURGER is not visible in your Fiddle. Have you tried my snippet here in the page by running it? Was it not working for you even here in the fiddle? Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant in your fiddle I found two problems: 1. HAM BURGER had `display: none;` not appearing on the page and 2. The link colors were white, so they were not visible even if we open the hamburger menu. I have adjusted these two problems and saved the resulting fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/47c5ohmy/